# How to test ethernet adapter?

Tags: ethernet, adapter

Is there a way in Ubuntu to test your Ethernet adapter to see whether it's working correctly or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Identify ethernet Interfaces

```
 ifconfig -a | grep eth
```

To see more information regarding ethernet

```
sudo lshw -class network
```

For more Information refer to [Docs](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.10/serverguide/network-configuration.html)

Comment: Can we check from ifconfig that an Ethernet card is healthy?

Comment: you can see the details in lshw -class network: size, capacity, capabilities, configuration( broadcast:(if yes, your ethernet card is healthy),speed) etc.,