# Why can't I have internet on this ubuntu machine?

Tags: networking, network-manager, internet, ethernet

This question might be extremely stupid. I have been working with linux for a couple of years now on embedded environments. But I have difficulties to have internet on my ubuntu machine at home.

I have one laptop running Linux mint where I can just plug in the Ethernet cable and it works out of the box. But when it comes to the other machine running ubuntu 14.04.4 just plugging in the Ethernet cable doesn't give it access to internet.

I don't have access to the router or whatsoever.

what are the steps I should follow to track down the issue?

**Evolution of the situation**

- Networking is enabled. It sees there is a wired connection when I plug in the cable, it tries to connect, but after some time a message automatically pops up saying "Disconnected - you are now offline. Network" with that empty "circle section" symbol
- I changed the line saying "managed=false" in `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` to "managed=true"
- this is my current screen: 
  [image: Screen]

Answer (score 0):

You say you don't have access to the router. I suggest you ask the administrator of the router whether he has enabled MAC filtering. If so, the administrator needs to add the MAC address of your machine to the router. Hope this helps.

Comment: unfortunately this is not an option for me...

Comment: I think you need to make sure your network adapter is healthy. Perhaps this link is helpfull: https://askubuntu.com/questions/395101/how-to-test-ethernet-adapter